# gsm-ussd gives device busy or error (100)

Tags: networking, modem, 3g

I am using gsm-ussd to try and query my data balance from my 3G modem.

When I issue the commands

```
gsm-ussd -m /dev/ttyUSB0 '*188#'
```

or

```
gsm-ussd -m /dev/ttyUSB2 '*188#'
```

I get either "Device or resource busy" (when it is in used and connected) or "Unknown error (100)".

My device (Huawei E173) seems to create 3 devices in /dev, namely `ttyUSB0`, `ttyUSB1` and `ttyUSB2`. None of them work, and ttyUSB1 gives a somewhat different problem, as it just give the following message:

```
* Wrong modem device (use -m <dev>)?
* Modem broken (no reaction to AT)
```

**UPDATE** I found the following post, but I am already doing what it says: http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/382977-8-ta-E173-on-openSUSE-with-USSD-setup

Comment: Have a look on Vodaphone Mobile Connect for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Huawei E1780 which also creates /dev/ttyUSB0 , /dev/ttyUSB1 and /dev/ttyUSB2

```
gsm-ussd --device /dev/ttyUSB2 --no-cleartext '*100#'
```

works for me. You can also add `--debug` maybe that helps finding the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This does not answer the question.

Comment: Uhhhm. You are right. Let me rephrase this:
You may want to try adding `--no-cleartext`. I shared my personal experience since it seemed close to the OP's problem: 
 a *Huawei* modem, 
 that exposes *three* ttyUSB devices, and 
 I got `modem broken` when I didn't use `no-cleartext` (maybe I should have mentioned that before)
If I read it right, it is noted [here](http://linux.zum-quadrat.de/#category2) that the program contains a list of modems that are *known* to require `no-cleartext` and for all *non-known* devices it does send it in clear text. Alternatively, look at (post) `--debug`